# I have an Interface of which an openApi output, I override some methods (Get and Put) of it in my controller. I can't send request with those methods

Tags: java, spring, server, internals

In my project, we use api first design approach and we have some autocreated classes/interfaces as an output of openApi. I override a GET and a PUT method in this interface, then I send requests through those methods on Postman and/or swagger, I receive below errors in postman and console:
{
"timestamp": "2023-02-02T17:25:26.548+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"path": "/con"
}

and

javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'com.xxxxx.xxxxxx.swagger.model.ConDto$ProviderEnum'. Check configuration for 'provider'

After that I have created my manual HTTP methods in my controller, and they work correct. I really spent really long time on this, however I am still away from the solution. Please excuse me since I am a junior Java Spring Boot Developer.

I created replica HTTP methods and worked on them, they work correct, so I cant get why the one coming from Interface does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Size` annotation for string length min/max value. It can't be used for `ProviderEnum` as exception message indicates.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/3.1/reference/en/html_single/